# How do I create my own realm model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am trying to learn Realm model with objective C. I want to know how to create our own .realm file and see the realm file in realm browser. Following is my code.

-In Specimen.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@interface Specimen : RLMObject//: NSObject
    @property NSString *name;
    @property NSString *specDescription;
    @property NSInteger latitude;
    @property NSInteger longitude;
    @property NSDate *date;
@end
```

-In UIViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Specimen.h"


@interface ViewController ()
{
    Specimen *first;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    first = [[Specimen alloc] init];

    first.name = @"first specimen";
    first.specDescription = @"some description";
    first.latitude = 12;
    first.longitude = 15;
    first.date = [NSDate date];

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm transactionWithBlock:^{
        [realm addObject:first];
    }];

    NSLog(@"Object added in realm");
}
```

Build gets succeeded. The last log too is shown on console.But I don't understand where to see the Specimen object as default realm always has person and dog objects only.
So I need to know how to create my own realm and then add the object and access it through realm browser.

Answer (score 0):

From Realm [official document](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#realms).

> Configuring things like where your Realm files are stored is done
>   through
>   [RLMRealmConfiguration](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealmConfiguration.html).

Example:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

// Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
config.fileURL = [[[config.fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent]
                      URLByAppendingPathComponent:username]
                      URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"realm"];

// Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
[RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
```

> You can have multiple configuration objects, so you can control the
>   version, schema and location of each Realm independently:

```
RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];

// Get the URL to the bundled file
config.fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyBundledData" withExtension:@"realm"];

// Open the file in read-only mode as application bundles are not writeable
config.readOnly = YES;

// Open the Realm with the configuration
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:config error:nil];

// Read some data from the bundled Realm
RLMResults<Dog *> *dogs = [Dog objectsInRealm:realm where:@"age > 5"];
```

Comment: Thank you!:) Will try this.